# Dataset: How to capture the primary key value returned by SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset, tableadapter

I'm using a dataset. I have a table Adapter called **PackageTableAdapter**, which contains a method called **InsertPackage**.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Packages] ([UserID], [Name]) VALUES (@UserID, @Name)

//Return the PackageID value for the newly created record...
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

This table adapter is being used by a middle tier class, with the below code:

```
private PackagesTableAdapter _packagesTableAdapter = null;
protected PackagesTableAdapter Adapter
{
    get
    {
        if (_packagesTableAdapter == null)
            _packagesTableAdapter = new PackagesTableAdapter();

        return _packagesTableAdapter;
    }
}    

public bool AddPackage(string PackageName)
{
    // Create a new PackageRow instance
    Album.PackagesDataTable packages = new AlbumCongo.PackagesDataTable();
    Album.PackagesRow package = packages.NewPackagesRow();

    // Add the new package
    package.Name = PackageName;
    packages.AddPackagesRow(package);
    int rowsAffected = Adapter.Update(packages);       

    // Return true if precisely one row was inserted,
    // otherwise false
    return rowsAffected == 1;        
}
```

How do I capture the primary key of the newly created package (the one that's supposed to returned by the **SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()** statement)?

**EDIT**

Instead of returning a bool value, I'd like to return a custom object that contains both the bool value and an int representing the ID of the newly created row.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: If you're using data adapters, you can check out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ks9f57t0.aspx.  You'll probably have to wrangle your own custom object though.

Comment: In the code, there's a way of telling how many rows were affected. Isn't there an easy way for retrieving the newly created ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you have to make the return type of the insert method to `Scaler`. You can also do so by right clicking the properties of your `insert Method properties`.

Secondly you can get the ID by calling the `Adapter method` like this:

```
Int32 ID = Convert.ToInt32(Adapter.Insert(parameters...);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the PackageID on the DataRow object AFTER the Adapter.Update call.